# Custom folders for video content on Wowza Server

Tags: android, streaming, wowza

I'm developing a video streaming app for android. I've used Wowza Media Server for this purpose, but the problem is that all video recordings are saved in Content folder inside Wowza installation folder.

Is it possible to save video files of each publisher in separate folder e.g.

```
   Vidoes of PublisherA be saved in  ...\Content\PublisherA
   Vidoes of PublisherB be saved in  ...\Content\PublisherB
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.
Following the article **How to record live streams (Wowza Streaming Engine)** > **Recording tab** > **Path**

> By default, the files are stored in the server content directory. If you want to store files in a different location, make sure that it exists on the computer and then specify its physical path. The path value can't contain any of the following symbols: less-than (<), greater-than (>), quotation (' and "), backslash (), pipe (|), question mark (?), and asterisk (*) characters.

You can use Wowza REST APIs http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?711-How-to-use-cURL-to-query-Wowza-REST-APIs#createrecord

1. Before we start, in my experience, you should add your IP address to **IPWhiteList**, by editing the file **[install-dir]/conf/Server.xml**. 
   For example:

   ```
   <IPWhiteList>127.0.0.1,14.177.13.7,14.162.13.7</IPWhiteList>
   ```
2. Restart your Wowza Streaming Engine.
3. Use cURL like they wrote, change **[outputPath]** to your PublisherA or PublisherB.